# Behaviour of arrow functions outside an ES6 React class constructor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-redux, arrow-functions

I have a simple piece of code in a project using react + react-redux with es6 (through babel):

```js
class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  // problematic piece of code: 
  showLockTimer = setTimeout(this.authenticate, 2000);

  leaveAnimationTimer = setTimeout(() => {
     this.setState({ hide: true }); // setState is correctly called
  }, 1000);

  authenticate = () => { // Never runs.
    // do some stuff...
    this.props.showLock();
  } 
}
```

For some reason, the authenticate method is never called... But if I put the setTimeout inside the class constructor, it works:

```js
class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  // This is the only changed code:
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.showLockTimer = setTimeout(this.authenticate, 2000);
  }

  leaveAnimationTimer = setTimeout(() => {
     this.setState({ hide: true }); // setState is correctly called
  }, 1000);

  authenticate = () => { // Now it runs!
    // do some stuff...
    this.props.showLock();
  } 
}
```

I thought I understood the `this` binding quite well, with arrow functions, but I can't understand why does this happen? I tried to google a lot for this issue and also read similar questions on SO but can't seem to find anything explaining it.

Sorry if this is a duplicate question.

Comment: In first example, move `authenticate` method above `ShowLockTimer`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In first example, you use `this.authenticate` before it even exists. Wrapping it in another arrow function `() => {this.authenticate()}` will make this work

Comment: Oh my... I can't believe it was that simple! So, the order I define class methods in javascript is important? 
What was happening in the end is the constructor is only called after the object is initialized with its methods?

Comment: Class methods can be defined in any order, but these aren't class methods, they are public class fields. Properties like `foo = ...` in a class body run just like they were in the class constructor where `super()` is, so the ordering matters.